# Virtual-box failed to start VM VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND

Tags: windows-10, vagrant, virtualbox, remote-desktop

When I run `vagrant up` I get this error

```
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["startvm", "3ae7b70c-8ea1-417a-ab67-99aef96624f8", "--type", "headless"]

Stderr: VBoxManage.exe: error: Failed to open/create the internal network 'HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #2' (VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND).
VBoxManage.exe: error: Failed to attach the network LUN (VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole
```

I found the solution here: https://www.howtoforge.com/setup-a-local-wordpress-development-environment-with-vagrant/ which is to update the driver of `VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter`

But the problem is I am remotely connected to the machine. So I am afraid that the network settings may lose my remote connection. Also, I cannot reboot the machine.

Is it safe to follow the steps mentioned in the link above which should not disconnect me? If not, is there any alternative way?

Answer (score 28):

Recently I have struggled with this issue. I tried many times to solve the issue. Sometimes I was able to run my vagrant machines successfully but how I did was not sure because I was trying lot of options. But finally, I found a way to solve it. It's pretty simple and tricky.
Solution:

Once you get this error on your terminal, just open your computer network adaptors from the control panel. Select the adaptor which was created for that virtual box. simply disable once and enable again. then run vagrant up command. That's it. the problem is gone.

```
- Start --> Network status --> Change adaptor options --> (select the Ethernet adaptor - In my case it is Ethernet4) 
- Right click --> Disable and right click --> Enable
- vagrant up
```

[image]

Comment: windows systems in a nutshell. just restart, that's it!

Comment: it worked for me as well i have just restarted each Virtual Box Host-Only adaptor and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and could not resolve it by changing properties in Network Adapters.

Then i reinstalled Virtual Machine by below command and it worked fine:

```
V:\softwares>VirtualBox-6.0.4-128413-Win.exe -msiparams NETWORKTYPE=NDIS5
```

Answer (score 0):

I just

> virtualBox only ethernet

disabled and before enabling

> VirtualBox NDIS6 Network Driver is checked

make sure

```
    - Start --> Network status --> Change adaptor options --> (select the Ethernet adaptor - In my case it is Ethernet4)
```

- Right click --> Disable and right click --> Enable
- vagrant up